# Help me finish this TSQL case query

Tags: t-sql

I'm forced to use stone knives and bear skins at work and unfortunately LINQ has been too good to me. What is wrong here:

```
SELECT cat_id, cat_parent, CASE WHEN LEN(cat_name) > 36 THEN SUBSTRING(cat_name,0,36) + '...' ELSE cat_name FROM Categories WHERE cat_parent != 0 AND cat_dir = 'Manufacturing'
```

I get this error:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CASE` missing `END` near `FROM`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT cat_id, cat_parent, 
CASE WHEN LEN(cat_name) > 36 THEN SUBSTRING(cat_name,0,36) + '...' ELSE cat_name END FROM Categories WHERE cat_parent != 0 AND cat_dir = 'Manufacturing'
```

I added END after cat_name before FROM

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT cat_id, cat_parent, CASE WHEN LEN(cat_name) > 36 THEN SUBSTRING(cat_name,0,36) + '...' ELSE cat_name END AS cat_name FROM Categories WHERE cat_parent != 0 AND cat_dir = 'Manufacturing'
```

It is missing an END for the CASE